# Website monthly visits are (daily visits x 30)?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, ads

I'm trying to estimate if showing ads on my website can become the main source of income by estimating the traffic of somewhat similar sites.

There are several websites, offering traffic statistics and presenting similar data. For instance, here is their statistics for `stackoverflow.com`:

http://www.similarweb.com/website/stackoverflow.com
http://www.trafficestimate.com/stackoverflow.com
http://www.siteworthtraffic.com/report/stackoverflow.com

According to these data, `stackoverflow.com` receives just around 150 million monthly visits. Does it mean that I should divide this number by 30 in order to get the number of daily visits, resulting in only 5 million visits a day, which is worth only ~15 000$ income a day? Because that's quite a low number for such a monster.

Or in reality it receives around 150 million users each day, making around 500 000$ a day?

---

Another case - `VK.com`:

http://www.trafficestimate.com/vk.com

http://www.similarweb.com/website/vk.com#overview

http://www.siteworthtraffic.com/report/vk.com

According to `vk.com` they have 350 millions active users. So the data, presented by trafficestimate, similarweb and siteworthtraffic don't look consistent.

---

Another case - `meduza.io`.

`meduza.io` is a news site, which was created by ~30 people team, who left `lenta.ru` after polytical persecution of their chief editor. They're making ~3 million visitors a month or ~ 10 million page views.

http://www.trafficestimate.com/meduza.io

http://www.similarweb.com/website/meduza.io#overview

With 10$/1000 page views, they could achieve just 100 000$/month, which is barely or not enough to pay salaries to 30 people in Europe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

The question is how many users are hitting stack overflow a day based off the users information.

Monthly visits are an estimate of the total month. So dividing by 30 will give you the ballpark per day. 5,000,000 a day.

You mentioned that the revenues would be quite low. Your estimates however are off. The ad revenue is much higher than you are projecting. I've worked on a few smart phone apps that anonymize user data and it is monetized at roughly 20 cents a user. your estimate of 15,000 a day for 5,000,000 users has ad revenue at .003 cents a user.

I am not sure what produces the highest revenue but I imagine a site specializing in computer code would have larger ad revenue then a sire focused around gardening.

I hope that helps.

Comment: ODYodel, thanks for answering! I estimate average CPM for desktop ads to be around 3$ per 1000 page views: http://monetizepros.com/cpm-rate-guide. I've read that good websites, such as Huffingtonpost make 10$ per mile, but that's a really hight CPM. Agreed, CPM varies by site theme, in tech and finance it averages 5$/mile, highest among industries, in sports - 1$/mile, in "gardening" even lower than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep in mind that dividing monthly users by 30 to get daily users is NOT super accurate. A month is a longer time period and more repeat users are removed from the monthly bucket than the daily bucket. In other words, there are many more users who return every month vs returning very day, so using the monthly figures to estimate daily users could significantly understate your forecasts *especially* if you have a new website with a lot of new visitors.

For a comprehensive difference between daily vs monthly users, visit [Occam's Razor](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/standard-metrics-revisited-6-daily-weekly-monthly-unique-visitors/).

Comment: Thanks for answering, silky_axis. Is it correct to calculate total number of page views a month as (monthly visitors x page views), according to similarweb? So, for http://www.similarweb.com/website/kaushik.net 510k*1.7 = 867k page views?

Comment: Yes, but only because the Pageviews number seems to be actually Pageviews Per Visit (PPV). Hence, monthly visitors x PPV will give you total PVs.